# How do I determine eigenvalues in matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulation, eigenvalue

Assume I have the model of a complex continuous system which consists of several differential equations as follows:

```
f = 1/(ura235 + 2.43*plu239 + 2.679*plu241) 
d/dt ura236 = (.016*ura235 - 0.0012*uran236)*f 
d/dt uran235 = -0.106*f*ura235
.
.
.
```

How do I determine the eigenvalues of such series of equations in Matlab without having to manually form the Jacobian matrix?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Sorry, its only in the movies where you can just tell the computer to sequence a piece of alien viral DNA, having it return a magic vaccine for the deadly alien disease it causes, and do all that within seconds. You still need to think about what you are doing, to know what the numbers are in your equations, and to understand the mathematics that you wish to do, writing out the equations yourself. Perhaps next year, when there are 1048576 core machines available, all of that will no longer be necessary.

Comment: I was told by a professor in the university that it's possible! If it's not possible then there certainly must be a workaround. What you are suggesting exactly? Doing all the math by hand????

Comment: Oh, mi gawd! All of that math? Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this without forming the Jacobian. If this is a nonlinear set of equations, then simply plug in at a given value of the solution and extract eigenvalues. I believe eig(A) will do this for you.